# Как взаимно заменить числа в файле

Tags: c++, файлы, строки

Всем доброго времени суток,

Есть такая вот задачка:

Разработать программу для заполнения файла целыми значениями, вводимыми с клавиатуры, окончание ввода – пустая строка. Проверить, стоит ли в файле минимальное значение раньше максимального, и если это не так, поменять их местами.

Файл прога заполняет, значения считывает и присваивает в min и max, но о том, чтобы хотя бы просто поменять местами min с max'ом (Не учитывая их позиции) речи пока не идёт. Прога пытается это сделать, но выходит не то, что требуется.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что и где не так?

Заранее спасибо.

[image: Вводимые значения]

[image: Результат работы]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int s = 0, s2 = 0, p, min = 0, max = 0;
    string S , R;
    fstream F;
    F.open("Numbers.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    do {
        int k = 0;
        cout << "Введите число: ";
        cin >> k;
        F << k << endl;
        s++;
    } while (s < 5);
    F.seekg(0, SEEK_SET);
    while (!F.eof())
    {
        F >> p;
        if (p < min) min = p;
        if (p > max) max = p;
    }
    F.close();
    F.open("Numbers.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    F.seekg(0, SEEK_SET);
    while (s2 < 5)
    {
        F >> p;
        if (p == min)
        {
            F.seekp(s2) << max;
            s2++;
        }
        else if (p == max)
        {
            F.seekp(s2) << min;
            s2++;
        }
        else s2++;
    }
    F.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поменяйте логику программы - сначала считайте все числа из стандартного потока ввода в последовательный контейнер, потом проведите требуемые операции по поиску/обмену элементов, а затем выведите результат в файл.

Comment: О том, чтобы вывести числа из файла в массив или вектор я думал, но надеялся обойтись без них, видимо не судьба :)